# Kendo UI DropDownBox quickly opens and closes when clicking on down arrow only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am trying to implement a simple Kendo UI DropDownList widget using AngularJS directive like below.

```
<select data-ng-init="model=0" data-kendo-dropdownlist data-k-data-source="[0,1,2,3]" style="width:56px"
                data-k-ng-model="model" data-on-change="modelChangeHandler(model)" data-k-value-primitive="true"></select>
```

Everything works fine and as expected expect in IE. In IE, when clicking on the [image]downward arrow, the widget quickly opens and closes without allowing the user to select a value from the list of values. Clicking on other areas of the widget allows the user to make a selection and then it dismisses which is the expected behavior.

The framework information are given below.

- Kendo UI Version : 2017.2.621
- Kendo UI Theme   : Bootstrap v3
- jQuery Version   : 1.10.2 with jQuery Migrate v1.4.1
- Bootstrap Version: 3.3.2
- AngularJS Version: 1.5.8

This issue only occurs in IE. Spent a lot of time investigating this with no luck. Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: could you reproduce the same issue in https://plunk.co or https://dojo.telerik.com/ ?

Comment: There are some known issues with IE on Kendo. Try to emulate Edge on your internet explorer inspector window to see if it works properly.